# First time using AJAX, JSON loop via AJAX with data on several pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

First time AJAX user here.. I have 15 sets of data that I'm wanting the user to bring in at a time. ie:

```
{"status":"Success","message":"My contents","data":[
  {"Contents":{"id":"1","Type":"fb","profileId":"123456","profileName":"Test1","profileImage":"https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-xfp1\/t1.0-1\/p50x50\/10337453_7117502132131244_84974578537125246499_t.jpg","postMessage":"Hello \u2022 Test \u2022 testing message \u2022"}},
  {"Contents":{"id":"2","Type":"fb","profileId":"1234567","profileName":"Test2","profileImage":"https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-xfp1\/t1.0-1\/p50x50\/10347453_7117503245184844_8497457853733242234_t.jpg","postMessage":"Hello \u2022 Test \u2022 testing message \u2022"}}
]}
```

Those initial 15 use the url `http://www.example.com/services/request/` and after that the user can press a "load more" which then gets the next 15 from `http://www.example.com/services/request/page2`, "load more" clicked again and get from `http://www.example.com/services/request/page3` etc.

I realised I will need to do a few things here:
 - On document load, run the first ajax request
 - Possibly parse JSON using `.stringify` although not using it in my attempt below, unsure if needed?
 - Add "load more" function so when the user presses it, it will get data from the next page and so forth

For each object in the array the data should be added as new `div`'s within `container`, i.e. with the first object:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="fb"> <!--type as class-->
    <div class="name">Test1</div> <!--text from profileName-->
    <div class="image"><img src="https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-xfp1\/t1.0-1\/p50x50\/10337453_7117502132131244_84974578537125246499_t.jpg" /></div><!--image url from profileImage-->
    <div class="message">Hello \u2022 Test \u2022 testing message \u2022</div><!--text from postMessage-->
  </div> <!--end of generated object-->
</div> <!--//container-->
```

**My attempt for the on document load (initial request):**

```
    $(function() { //document ready
        $.getJSON('http://www.example.com/services/request/', function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(index) {
          $('#container').append(
            $('<div class="'+data.type+'">'), 
            $('<div class="name">').html(data.profileName),
            $('<div class="image">').html("<img src='+data.profileImage+' < />"),
            $('<div class="message">').html(data.postMessage)
          )
        });
    });
});
```

Ok I have this appending to `#container` but not correctly.. why? Also, the "undefined" div which should be `fb` class, should wrap around the other div's underneath it.

```
<div class="undefined"></div>
<div class="name"></div>
<div class="image">
<img <="" src="+data.profileImage+">
</div>
<div class="message"></div>
```

Comment: You are missing some concatenation operators `+` in the script as well as leaving some String literals unterminated.

Comment: Also, what's the backend? .net? php? java?

Comment: you parse json with JSON.parse or even easier, $.getJSON

Comment: @KevinBowersox updated again, thanks for the heads up. Any ideas on the entire function for this and the load more?

Comment: Those semicolons between the arguments of the `append()` call should be commata

Comment: Thanks @r3wt if you have any edits to make to my code, including the "load more" function which I have no idea how I'm going to do, please feel free to add an answer with some info. so I can learn from it.

Comment: Use a function which you can pass the page number, and a counter variable that is used in the button's click handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things: Put that request you already have working in a separate function, eg. `loadPage` (so you don't have to rewrite the function). Have it not load direct url, but to take it as a param.

So, on document load, set a `page` variable to 1, and start the first run with that page.

Add that "Load more" button and the button handler which will call the loadPage and inc the page variable.

eg.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // set this here so that it is kept in reach.
    var page = 2;

    // this will call the required url, assemble it as needed.
    function loadPage(page) {
        var url = 'http://www.example.com/services/request/' + page;
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index) {
                $('#container').append(<YOURDATAHERE>);
            });
          )
        }
    }

    // This is the Load More handler - attach it to the button.

    function loadMore() {
        loadPage('page' + page);
        page = page + 1;
    };

    // Now make the first, initial run with no 'page1' as in your example.
    loadPage('');
});
```

You can, in similar way, implement a paginator if required.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer firstly and secondly for your great commenting to help me understand the way to structure this. I have also updated my `.append` as when I ran it on my end it wasn't returning any data :(

Comment: I know about that, it was an Enter slip. Thanks @Bergi for fixing it :)

Comment: @Zlatko is my `.append` data structured correctly in my example code in my question? Just doesn't want to append any of that data from the url to `#container` and console provides no errors.

Comment: @Zlatko I've updated the question again as it is appending but not correctly :/

Comment: You've got it wrong, because you have $.each(data, function(index){});  and keep using data. Try making it $.each(data, function(key, val) { console.log('Data key: ', key, ', Value: ', val)});. What do you get there?

Comment: Thanks, I get: Data key: status , Value: Success 
Data key: message , Value: My contents Data key: data , Value: [Object { Contents={...}} and inside the object shows.. comments
 
 null
 
created
 
 "2014-06-23 07:26:19"
 
id
 
 "21"
 
likes
 
 "0" etc etc. That's my structure at the start of my question just without things I don't need to use :)

Comment: @Zlatko in this case do I have to use `data.data` to get the object "data" within "data" or even `data.contents`?

Comment: Well, the data is already the object here, just loop what you need. It looks like you'd need to $.each(data.data...) or something to make this better. What if you put $.each(data.data, function...) instead?

Comment: data.data, it looks like it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56155/discussion-between-zlatko-and-dt-dtdg).

Comment: @Zlato I'm getting this in console with `data.data`: Console Log displays "Data key: 0 , Value: Object {...." happy to discuss in chat.

Comment: Have another question that leads on from this one, you might be able to help? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398870/masonry-not-working-using-ajax-and-infinite-scroll

Comment: Not on that one, not using masonry. G'luck anyway.

Answer (score 3):

While @Zlatko has covered the "load more" functionality pretty well, here is how to improve your DOM code so that it is structured like in the example markup you provided:

```
var cont = $('#container');
$.each(data.data, function(index, obj) {
    var item = obj.Contents;
    cont.append(
      $('<div>', {"class": item.Type}).append(
        $('<div>', {"class":"name", text:item.profileName}),
        $('<div>', {"class":"image"}).append(
          $('<img>', {src:item.profileImage})
        ),
        $('<div>', {"class":"message", text:item.postMessage})
      )
    );
});
```

Comment: if I use `data.data` then I get the following with your code: <div>
<div class="name"></div>
<div class="image">
<img>
</div>
<div class="message"></div>
</div> with no data in there

Comment: I'm getting this in console with `data.data`: Console Log displays "Data key: 0 , Value: Object {...."

Comment: Thanks for the hint, fixed and tested now.

Comment: Thanks! Getting there :D Now getting TypeError: item is undefined
 

$('<div>', {"class": item.type}).append(

Comment: Hm. Check your JSON response whether there are objects in the `data` array that do not have `Contents`

Comment: You're a genius! :) I had a typo with `contents` in `obj.contents`. Pulling in everything perfectly now, thank you!

Comment: Have another question that leads on from this one, you might be able to help? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398870/masonry-not-working-using-ajax-and-infinite-scroll

Comment: You seem to know AJAX :D any help with that new question IF you have a few minutes would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know masonry well. But +1 for having asked a new question instead of discussing everything in comments :-)

Comment: Thanks Bergi :) feel free to open discussion if you think you could help with the other bits of it.. can show you a link if you like, again only if you have time.

Answer (score 1):

1st off, don't use each with a callback of data.

on the front end, you could use JSON.parse(data) to get your data into an object. like so

```
var records = data,
var length = records.data.Contents.length;//you seem to have overcomplicated your object structure for no reason.
for(var iterator = 0; iterator < length; iterator++)
{
    //now you can access your properties like so
    var Type = records.data.Contents[iterator].Type,
    var id   = records.data.Contents[iterator].id;//you can access properties of your objects as simple as this.
    if(Type == 'Fb')
    {
        //any properties unique to this type go here.
            //example
            var ProfileId = records.data.Contents[iterator].ProfileId;
        $('#somediv ul').append('<li target="'+id+'">'+Type+'<a href=?profile'+ProfileId+'</li>');
    }
    //so on and so forth for all your various Types
}
```

now when a user needs to load more

```
$('#load-morestuff').click(function(){
    var lastid = $(this).parents('ul > li:last-child').attr('target');//we get the id of the last result turned from  the ajax request(s)
    //you may have to play with this a bit in order to get the last child. i don't have reference on hand or time to test it, but i recall doing something
    //similar in a previous project.
    $.get('someurl&id='+lastid, function(data){
        //now you've sent the lastid. the serverside script should fetch startign from this last id. presto, you have jquery pagination.
        //now it is the same as the first example you append it to the divs. cool stuff eh?
    });
});
```

Comment: My mistake, didn't see he was using getJSON

Comment: I'm a bit of a beginner, can i ask you what the performance/functional difference between `.each()` and manual for looping over the object? it looks like i could shorten alot of my codebase based on your suggestions. i just assumed each was for dom elements but didn't know you could use it on objects. thats pretty awesome.i clearly have much to learn still about javascript.

Comment: Oh, I think your version would be even better (at least in some cases,like this), I just used .each because the OP was using it. Didn't want to confuse him with that bit.

Comment: Thanks :) happy to stick with my original, sorry @r3wt

Comment: Have another question that leads on from this one, you might be able to help? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398870/masonry-not-working-using-ajax-and-infinite-scroll

Comment: @DT.DTDG That question is a bit out of my league i'm afraid.I would probably do more harm than good.

Comment: @r3wt thanks and no problem, if you get a chance here's the example working demo http://desandro.github.io/masonry/demos/infinite-scroll.html and I'm trying to implement something quite similar.